# When I moved from study of JavaScript to study jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which is better, learn the basics of JavaScript, and then jQuery

Or master JavaScript and then learn  jQuery

Now I know the basics well But I did not write many exercises of javascript

thanks

sorry about My bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with javascript.

If you want to go deeper into the javascript, want to experiment with it, then become a master in javascript. In that case I will suggest you to read this excellent [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) by Douglas Crockford. Becoming a master of something never hurts. But if you want to become a developer and want to only build websites with javascript, then learn the core basics and move on to learning jquery.

Again, whatever you do, you should have a clear understanding about the basics of javascript. You should, at least, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/a_re-introduction_to_javascript) excellent article and understand how objects in javascripts work, what are prototypes, what datatypes are there. There are also many other resources on javascript on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [Opera Developers Network](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc). [Google](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/) also has some excellent resources on javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Always better to learn the language before learning a framework, as JQuery isn't the only JS framework.

If you know the language, you'll be able to understand whatever framework you want to use.

Comment: Well what is the required level of javascript knowledge Before using jquery .. experience for one year, for example

Comment: I think you can actually study both at the same time. JQuery can indeed taught you JavaScript, if you study it from the inside, and if you try to understand how they are doing stuff. Always keep in mind that you need to lear JavaScript while experiencing with both JS and JQuery.

Comment: thank you I will try to study both .. Do you recommend a good book on jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The references I have used in the past, ending up with the good understanding of them both are as follows:

- Javascript: http://eloquentjavascript.net/
- JQuery:     http://jqfundamentals.com/ by Rebecca Murphey.

Hope these help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you start with reading this book on Javascript > [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748)

It's the best book out there to understand the fundamentals of Javascript and how it actually differs from the rest of the language. What are the good parts and what are the bad parts.

Once you are done with that, then you'll be better off learning jQuery and start doing examples.

Comment: Yea, you need to understand the fundamentals of Javascript. It's very different from standard languages like C#, Java and even dynamic ones like Python/Ruby